# Lazy Exception problem in UserDetails when getting roles

Tags: java, spring, security, lazy-evaluation

When logging in I am getting this error:

```java
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: io.exping.rpgtodoapp.user.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:614) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1865) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:414) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:508) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at io.exping.rpgtodoapp.user.MyUserPrincipal.getAuthorities(MyUserPrincipal.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
```

**MyUserPrincipal class:**

```java
@Transactional
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private final User user;

    public MyUserPrincipal(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(r -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

**Relation in User class:**

```java
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

**Relation in role class:**

```java
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

When changing fetching to eager I am getting weird loop. I double checked my database correctness (but I am beginner so maybe there is the problem idk). @Transactional annotation don t work too.

I tried to fix this for hours. Should I show more code for solution?
Thank you for responses!

Comment: Error clearly says: no Hibernate Session. You should open one before accessing the lazy loaded proxy. For example: sessionFactory.openSession();

Comment: That makes sense, I used entityManager, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced the same problem but this solution are not correct.

**First:**
The Problem occur because Hibernate sends two Selects statements to the SQL Server. The First statement selects the User `"Select * from User ..."` and then the Second Statement `"Select * from ROLES where username='username'"` ... And this is the Problem -> For the second Select-Statement Hibernate needs a Transaction -> **So the Solution is, you have to get hibernate to do a JOIN (because you need ONE Query)!** This happens because you have LAZY decalred.

**Second:**
Now you must enter your Repository and make a **LEFT JOIN FETCH** Statement -> In this case Hibernate will execute one Query with join!

For Example your Repository Class have the Method:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM APPUser u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.appuserroles WHERE u.username= :username")
Optional<APPUser> findUserWithRolesByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

If you use LEFT JOIN without FETCH then Hibernate will again execute two querys!

And be carreful, import the right package to overwritte the Querys:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably found the solution.
I used EntityManager in UserDetailsService implementation class.

**UserService implements UserDetailsService:**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService  {

@Autowired
private final UserRepository userRepository;

@PersistenceContext
private final EntityManager entityManager;
private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
    UsernameNotFoundException{

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    TypedQuery<Role> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r 
    JOIN r.users u WHERE u.id = :userId ", Role.class);
    query.setParameter("userId", user.getId());
    authorities = query.getResultList().stream().map(r -> new 
    SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new MyUserPrincipal(user, authorities);
}

public void save(User user){
    userRepository.save(user);
}

}
```

**MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails**

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

private final User user;
private final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public MyUserPrincipal(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.user = user;

    this.authorities = authorities;
}

    @Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    return authorities;
}
```